# references did not appear

Tags: bibtex

```
\documentclass[12pt,aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{bookman}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\graphicspath{{Arquivos/}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\CO}{Contexte scientifique et objectif}
\newcommand{\I}{Introduction}
\newcommand{\MM}{Modèle mathématique}
\newcommand{\SM}{Simulation numérique}
\newcommand{\C}{Conclusion}
\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection, 
    hideothersubsections, 
    sectionstyle=show/shaded,
]
\end{frame}
}
\title{...............}

\author[.....]{......}
\institute[IPT]{\large{;............} }
\date{May 20-24, 2019} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}




\section{\CO}
\begin{frame}{\CO}\pause

\end{frame}

\section{\I}
\begin{frame}{\I}\pause

\end{frame}

\section{\MM}
\begin{frame}{\MM}

\end{frame}

\section{\SM}
\begin{frame}{\SM}\pause
    \cite{FV}
\end{frame}

\section{\C}
\begin{frame}{\C}
\cite{CrPas}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Référence}
        \bibliographystyle{plain} 
        \bibliography{biblio} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\Large{\textbf{Merci pour votre attention}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you run the cycle `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`?

Comment: Thanks for reminding